# Draw USA map region wise using D3 and angular 6

Tags: d3.js, charts, angular6, geojson, topojson

I need to draw USA Map region wise in D3. It should be something similar to this.
[image: USA Map region wise]

I am taking reference from [this USA](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312) map which is showing data state wise. And I am able to create this state wise chart using D3 and angular 6. But

- How to get the geojson or topojson for Region wise data.
- I did not find any chart using D3 for this region wise also.
- Which one will be helpful geoJson or topojson. (As per my understanding and
  [this article](https://medium.com/@amy.degenaro/introduction-to-digital-cartography-geojson-and-d3-js-c27f066aa84) it will be topojson.)
- I am not getting any approach to draw to this,

**EDIT:** I am able to create the region chart using the approach which [andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106086/andrew-reid)  mentioned. **I want to create states outlines too**, but not getting any idea about that. Below is the approach which i used.

```
const svg = d3
  .select('#statesvg')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 960 600')
  .attr('width', this.width)
  .attr('height', this.height);
this.getUSData().subscribe(us => {
  svg
    .selectAll(undefined)
    .data(this.uRegionPaths)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', datum => {
      const feature = topojson.merge(
        us,
        us.objects.states.geometries.filter(state => {
          return datum.contains.indexOf(this.lookup[state.id]) > -1;
        })
      );

      return path(feature);
    })
    .attr('fill', d => {
      return this.sampleRegionData[d.name].color;
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .attr('stroke-width', 3);
});
```

And it looks somewhat similar to this. few states are missing as of now.(that is not an issue,)

[image: Region wise chart, few states are missing as of now]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topojson is converted to geojson when passed to d3.geoPath - you can use either. However, as the topojson API exposes a [merge](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#merge) method, topojson has a key advantage: we can use the topojson `us.json` file in your example to draw your map.

To draw a collection of states as one feature, we just need to merge them into one feature. To do so we use:

```
topojson.merge(us, us.objects.states.geometries.filter( /* some test */ )
```

Where we test each state to see if it belongs in the region at hand. This line will return a geojson feature containing the merged topojson features. We can then pass that to `d3.geoPath`.

To work with the `us.json` file linked to in your example, we need to consider how (and if) the states are identified in the data.

The `us.json` file doesn't come with an accompanying description of its meta data, but I can say that the id of each state is a numerical [FIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standard_state_code) code. So, unless we want to specify the regions numerically, we need to translate between number and abbreviation (or some other recognizable form). I'll just use a simple object to get abbreviation from FIPS number:

```
var lookup = {
    "53" : "WA",
    "41" : "OR",
    "6" : "CA",
    // ...
}
```

And now we can specify regions, say like:

```
var regions = [
  {"name": "northwest", "contains":[ "WA","OR","CA" ] }
  // ...
];
```

Now we can draw our regions:

```
var lookup = {
    "53" : "WA",
    "41" : "OR",
    "6" : "CA",
    // ...
}

var regions = [
  {"name": "northwest", "contains":[ "WA","OR","CA" ] }
  // ...
];

d3.json("us.json").then(function(us) {
  svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(regions)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function(region) {
      var feature = topojson.merge(us, us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(state) { 
         return region.contains.indexOf(lookup[state.id]) > -1; 
       }))
       return path(feature);
    })
});
```

If you want state outlines too - just draw the states in addition to the regions. [Here's the west coast](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/d37c67536a89a56fcb7eebd439f15082) using the above method, to draw additional regions, just add them to the regions array (while also adding necessary state codes to the lookup object).

Comment: I am able to create the region chart using the approach which you mentioned. I want to create states outlines too, but not getting any idea about that, I add my approach too in my question.

Comment: and how can i show text inside the regions,, I am able to show the text, but all regions text is coming at one location only.

Comment: For your first comment, you could draw the regions (fill only), the states or state mesh(stroke one), and then draw the regions *again*, with stroke only. This should order everything right. Text can be positioned by using a path centroid (see d3-geo docs), but that should be answered somewhere, try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353872/7106086)